# Redirect IOS app service calls to different environment services

Tags: api, redirect

My iPad app is developed by third party and it is calling my restful services for registration and login.
Now I want to launch iPad app from XCode project which is pointing to old service URLs and redirect service calls to invoke new service URLs without modifying the code.

Ex: login request coming to http://xx.com/login and redirect to http://xx.com/services/login by interpreting some tool.

Please advice me or let me know if there is any better approach.

Comment: this question is not about `ios`, `xcode`, `ipad` nor `ios-simulator`

Comment: "without modifying the code" - which code? The app's code or that of your web service?

Comment: @H2CO3: Without modifying my App's code.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.charlesproxy.com/ is what you want. This lets you breakpoint, forward, and do any kind of crazy stuff with your requests. Install on your mac, put it in the same wifi as your phone, and use your mac's ip as proxy.

Comment: use your mac's ip as proxy? how can I do that?

Comment: In the phone, inside the wifi settings, at the bottom.
In charles, proxy -> proxy settings and pick a port.

Comment: at the button? ..i tap on blue arrow , from there which one has to select?

Comment: Pick a port.?- this port is the one where I want to redact the incoming calls? if so I don't have a port on the server ..it has to hit load balancer url

Comment: @Feranndo: Making an app request from Xcode simulator, how can i redirect the incoming app request for rest service(https://sample/register) to another rest service(https://sample/servicesregister).

Answer (score 0):

I used MapRemote to redirect the url in Charles.
Had set Map from and Map to columns.